# How to start a custom binary with options and arguments from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I somehow can't figure out how to start a self-written programm with arguments from a shell script. If I'm in a folder whose parent folder contains the binary, then I can start the program with

```
$ ../binary --opt1 arg1 --opt2 arg2
```

Now, say the arguments and options are listed in a file args in the current folder.

args.txt:

```
--opt1 arg1 --opt2 arg2
```

If I'm trying to execute the binary from a shell script in the current folder like:

```
$ ./script.sh args.txt
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 1 ]
then
    exit 1;
 fi

 params=$(<"$1")

../binary "$params"
# ../binary <<<"$params" doesn't work either.
```

How can I make this work?

Edit (updated script):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 1 ]
then
    exit 1;
fi

params=$(<"$1")

START=$(date +%s)
../binary "$params"
# ../binary <<<"$params" doesn't work either.
END=$(date +%s)                                                                                                                             
DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))                                                                                   
echo "Test took $DIFF seconds"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command substituion:

```
$ ./script.sh args.txt
```

content of ./script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
../binary $(< "$1")
```

> **Command Substitution**
>
> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.  There are two forms:
>
> ```
>           $(command)
>    or
>           `command`
> ```
>
> Bash  performs  the  expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.  Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting.  The command substitution  `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.
>
> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by `$`, `, or `\`.  The first back‐quote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution. When using the `$(command)` form, all characters between the  parentheses  make up the command; none are treated specially.
>
> Command substitutions may be nested. To nest when using the backquoted form, escape the inner backquotes with backslashes. If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the results.

Comment: I know that, I want to call it from a script, because I'm embedding the command between two "time commands" to measure the latency. Maybe I should edit to clarify

Comment: I edited the answer. I tested it this way and it works fine for me.

Comment: Worked, but I think writing `"$1"` is more safe, because of word splitting.